# Getting Conky to run?

Tags: conky

I am running xubuntu 12.04 and was wondering how to make conky run, and how to configure it how I like. Is there a GUI to do this or is there a config file I need to edit? To install I ran

```
sudo apt-get install conky
```

Is there something else I need to do? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an amazing GUI called `conkey-manager`. You can use it to configure `conky`, manage themes, etc.

Install it by adding the PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

Then just run `conky-manager`.

Comment: Thanks, but sudo apt-add-repository doesn't work on my system.

Comment: Install it with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` or `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`.

Comment: Fun fact: You can do it through synaptic :) Thanks for the ppa and package names :)